# Onkeyup() not working

Tags: javascript, php

Every time I have changes on input tag with name 'qty' the onkeyup function in the script is not working, do I have problem with my selector? Because in the onkeyup function for the textbox there's no problem.

Comment: Will need to see some code or we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

your selectors were wrong. It should be like this;

```
$('table.order-list, input[name^="txt1"], input[name^="txt2"]').on("keyup", function    (event) {
        calculate($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
    $('div.panel1, input[name^="qty"]').on("keyup", function (event) {
        calculate($(this).closest("label"));
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction but it is not working. It happens that if I change the value in input tag name 'qty' the result in input tag name 'total' not change. But if I have change the value in either input tag name 'txt1' and 'txt2' it changes the result.